# Как проиграть mp4 файл в приложении?

Tags: android

Как добавить mp4 файл в приложение? Вот у меня есть 20 сек, видео инструкция для пользователя, как ее проиграть в приложении? Чтоб пользователь нажимал кнопку "старт" и открывается экран и там играет видео?

Comment: в VideoView пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

В моем случае VideoView мне помогло

1)Установил VideoView элемент в XML файл

2)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

//        Здесь нужно указать путь к своему файлу
    String videoSource = "android.resource://com.example.aleksey.firstwizard/" + R.raw.anim;
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
}
```

И все заработало